Working with SQLAlchemy and python. How can I get past Lazy Loading / Argument Errors
I've been trying to acquire a list of id's for all the accounts that a certain user follows. My database is defined below.

UserFollowers = Table(
    "UserFollowers",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("follower_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
)

UserBlocked = Table(
    "UserBlocked",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("blocked_user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(String, nullable=False)
    surname = Column(String, nullable=False)
    biography = Column(Text, default="I'm new! Just exploring.")
    iconid = Column(Integer)
    joined = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    verified = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    disabled = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    moderator = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    business = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    public = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    media = relationship("Media", backref="users")
    posts = relationship("Posts", backref="users")
    authtokens = relationship("AuthTokens", backref="users")
    moderation = relationship("Moderation", backref="users")
    usersettings = relationship("UserSettings", backref="users")
    comments = relationship("Comments", backref="users")
    likes = relationship("Likes", backref="users")
    messages = relationship("Messages", backref="users")
    followers = relationship(
        "Users",
        secondary=UserFollowers,
        primaryjoin=(UserFollowers.c.user_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(UserFollowers.c.follower_id == id),
        backref="following",
    )
    blockedusers = relationship(
        "Users",
        secondary=UserBlocked,
        primaryjoin=(UserBlocked.c.user_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(UserBlocked.c.blocked_user_id == id),
        backref="blocked_by",
    )


The issue I'm facing is that when I try to directly access a user.following object, I get:
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Users at 0x15e7251f340> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'following' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)

So, I'm trying to directly access the UserFollowers table and use a SELECT statement:
stmt = select([UserFollowers.c.user_id]).where(UserFollowers.c.follower_id == user_obj.id)

where user_obj.id is the id of the user who we want to get all the ids of people he is following.
This statement when executed returns the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=<UserFollowers>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)]. Did you mean to say select(Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=<UserFollowers>, primary_key=True, nullable=False))?

Any help at all would be appreciated, I'm not sure how to fix this utter mess.

The error message

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False)]. Did you mean to say select(Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False))?

explains the problem, albeit rather verbosely*.
The expression
select([UserFollowers.c.user_id]).where(...)

was valid in earlier versions of SQLAlchemy, but since v2.0 columns to be selected must be passed as individual positional arguments, not as a list.
This would work:
select(UserFollowers.c.user_id).where(...)

More generally
select(tbl.c.column1, tbl.c.column2, ...)

columns = [tbl.c.column1, tbl.c.column2, ...]
select(*columns)


* The error message displays the columns repr, which displays a lot of information about the column, perhaps obscuring the actual message.

Instead of acquiring all conditions of the remote object, I am able to avoid the error by using list manipulation to acquire the relevant result:
stmt = select(UserFollowers.c).where(UserFollowers.c.follower_id == user_obj.id)
result = session.execute(stmt)
following_user_ids = [row[1] for row in result]
return following_user_ids

